# How can I schedule a task in my django amazon product tracking project?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a **web-app** project with **Django**. It is an **Amazon product price tracker**. I want the app to **automatically scrape products in the product table to check if the price of the product has reduced or not**. I want to deploy the application once it is finished so it should work there too.

I looked for answered online but it seems that **cronjobs** and **celery** do not work for windows so is there any other ways I can achieve my goals.

I have created a function that needs to be executed once every day.

This is the function I want to execute every 24 hours.

```
def track():
    products = Product.objects.all()

    for product in products:
        new_data = getproduct(product.link)
        update_data(product, new_data)
```

I have tried the schedule library:

```
import schedule
import time
from .models import Product
from .utils import getproduct

schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(track)
```

- here getproduct is the method which scrapes the product data and product is the model

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario celery is the best option and yes you can run celery on windows too. Install rabbit mq and celery < 4 it will work. However, if you don't want to use celery there is another option [dajngo-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that you can use.

Comment: thanks for telling me about django-background-tasks. there is only one thing I didn't get that how can I run the task function without manually executing a code i.e python manage.py process_tasks this is the command I have to use to run the task but I want the task to run automatically only the first time a product is inserted in the database. Is there any way around it?

Comment: just like python manage.py runserver you have to keep process_tasks running in a separate process(terminal). and it will run your tasks